# want to send email in back ground in php

Tags: php, symfony, redis

Recently I am working on symfony. I have created a simple form and want to submit that form and send respons to user as email.

In `index` i have written as follow:

```
    $product=new Product();
    $product->setName('rohit');
    $product->setPass('rohit');

    $form=$this->createFormBuilder($product)
    ->add('name','text')
    ->add('pass','password')
    ->getForm();

    $name='rohit';
        return $this->render('EnsNewBundle:Email:ind.html.twig',
    array('form'=>$form->createView(),'name'=>$name));
```

and when i submit this form then the following action should perfom:

i) it should print `hello` and
ii) email process should be run in background.

I am trying to write as follow:

```
$client = new \Predis\Client();

      $client->lpush('emailid','ucerturohit@gmail.com');

      $u=$client->lrange('emailid',0,10);
  //notification_on_signup($u);

     var_dump($u);

    return $this->render('EnsNewBundle:Email:header.html.twig');
```

what should I correct in it to run efficiently

Comment: Check out [the section on email spooling](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/email/spool.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate PHP script which does the background work, and call this script in your main script.  The key is the &amp sign!

```
<?php
$command = "/usr/bin/php5 -f /var/www/my/php/file.php";

exec( "$command > /dev/null &", $arrOutput );
?>
```

Comment: The `<%` syntax for PHP has been discouraged for years. You should not recommend it ;)

Comment: You should use `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: Urg, didn't even see that I used <%.  Agree, it shouldn't be used!